# waking up a thread from sleep in response to an event c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Lets suppose i have 3 threads A, B and C

A starts B whereas C is an independent thread with no relation to either A or B. So now A calls B does some work and sleeps waiting for a signal from B or C to wakeup and start doing work again.

How can this cross thread event handling be achieved in C# ?

Comment: Check out the Monitor class.

Comment: Do you need A to run exactly as many times as it is signaled by B/C, even if both B and C signal 'at the same time'?

Comment: Don't use Sleep with Thread A, instead it should use something like `WaitOne` from AutoResetEvent, for example.  Thread B or C would explicitly signal this same event object, which "wakes up" Thread A.

Comment: @MartinJames lets assume that the B and C wont signal at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `ManualResetEvent` or an `AutoResetEvent` (based on the particular semantics you desire; without more info it's hard to say which is more appropriate).  Create the appropriate event object and share it with all three threads.  Have thread `A` wait on the event.  Either `B` or `C` can then set the event to wake up thread `A`.

Comment: This may not be enough, depending on the OP exact requirements.

Comment: @MartinJames It's appropriate in a large percent of situations.  If the OP is in a situation where this is insufficient he'll need to post the details for them to be addressed.  Covering every single possible case of notification in the event the OP may be in that circumstance is not realistic.